# Smoothie chart shows empty with electron vuejs

Tags: typescript, vue.js, electron

I'm running Electron with Vue 2.6 and Typescript to run my application. I created sample smoothie chart following tutorial [here](http://smoothiecharts.org/tutorial.html). This tutorial shows chart, but in my case, it shows empty.

**Main.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="dashboard-page">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Welcome</h1>
      <canvas id="smoothie" ref="refSmoothie" width="800" height="100"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import {
  Vue, Component, Watch, Ref,
} from 'vue-property-decorator'
import { State } from 'vuex-class'
import { SmoothieChart, TimeSeries } from 'smoothie'

export default class Connect extends Vue {
  @Ref() refSmoothie!: HTMLCanvasElement
  mounted() {
    const chart = new SmoothieChart()
    chart.streamTo(this.refSmoothie)
  }
}
</script>
```

**Problem**

> Smoothie chart doesn't show the chart and the canvas element was there. Is this have to do with Electron or Typescript?